# Swift - Filter out all decks where production exists using a complex sub-query

Tags: swift, mapreduce, filtering, map-function

I am working on a game project where there is this following relationship;

> Board -> Deck -> Cards <- Hand - Player
>
> Card - Production

More to put it more broadly;

- A `Board` has many decks
- A single `Deck` has many cards
- `Player` has a hand of cards
- Each card has a parent `deck`, an optional owner and optional production reference
- Production for the purposes of this question just a reference to `units: Int`
- A single deck has orders (an array of ints)

Or to put it more simply;

> Player holds many cards.  Each card has production units on them.

I wish to get a list of all decks which satisfies these specific rules

1. Only return decks where there are orders AND
2. Only return decks where there are owners (players) AND
3. Only return decks where the owners of the cards actually have
   production units.

I only care about decks where the owners have units to satisfy the orders.

I can do a filter for steps 1 and 2, but I get stuck on step 3.

My filter code is:

```
let filter1 = CustomFilter.filterDecksWithOrdersAndOwners(decks: decks)

        let filter2 = filter1.filter { (d: Deck) -> Bool in
            guard let owners = d.owners else {
                return false
            }

            let results = owners.filter({ (p: Player) -> Bool in

                return p.hand.cards.filter({ (c: Card) -> Bool in
                    guard let hasProduction = c.production else {
                        return false
                    }
                    return ((c.parent == d) && (hasProduction.units > 0))
                })
            })

            return results
        }
```

This code sadly seems too messy and returns an error where

`cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((Card) throws -> Bool)'`

A possible response would probably be;

> - Deck #1 has orders of [3,5,2] and has [3] owners (Sam, Alice, Mike)
>     But only Sam and Mike have production units
> - Deck #2 has orders of [1] and [1] owner (Mike)
>     Mike has 0 units
> - Deck #3 has no orders & no units and wouldn't be returned from my filter

**Question**

How can I return a filter of all decks where owners have production units > 0?

My code now follows;

---

Long code now follows;

A public gist can be made available if requested.

// Swift playground code

```
import Foundation
import GameplayKit

public struct Die {
    public static func roll() -> Int {
        let d6 = GKRandomDistribution.d6()
        return d6.nextInt()
    }
}

// Entity Description:
// Board -> Deck -> Cards <- Hand - Player
// Card - Production


class Board {
    var decks: [Deck] = [Deck]()

    init() {
        self.decks += (1...3).enumerated().map({ (index, _) -> Deck in
            return (Deck.init(name: "Deck #\(index + 1)"))
        })
    }
}

class Deck : Equatable, CustomStringConvertible
{
    let uuid: String = UUID().uuidString
    var cards: [Card] = [Card]()
    var orders: [Int] = [Int]()
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name

        self.cards += (1...4).enumerated().map({ (index, _) -> Card in
            return (Card.init(parent: self, name: "Card #\(index)"))
        })
        self.orders += (1...3).enumerated().map({ (index, _) -> Int in
            return (Die.roll())
        })
    }

    public var owners: [Player]? {
        return self.cards
            .lazy
            .flatMap { card in card.owner.map{ (card: card, owner: $0) } }
            .map { $0.owner }
    }
}

extension Deck {

    var description: String {
        return (self.name)
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: Deck, rhs: Deck) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.uuid == rhs.uuid)
    }
}

class Card : Equatable, CustomStringConvertible
{
    let uuid: String = UUID().uuidString
    weak var parent: Deck?
    weak var owner: Player?
    var production: Production?
    var name: String

    init(parent: Deck, name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.production = Production.init(parent: self)
    }

    func setOwner(player: Player) {
        self.owner = player
        self.production?.units = 1
    }
}

extension Card {
    var description: String {
        return (self.name)
    }
    public static func ==(lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.uuid == rhs.uuid)
    }
}

class Production {
    weak var parent: Card?
    var units: Int = 0

    init(parent: Card) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
}


// Player and Hand of cards

class Player {
    var name: String
    var hand: Hand!

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.hand = Hand.init(owner: self)
    }
}

class Hand {
    weak var owner: Player?
    var cards: [Card] = [Card]()

    init(owner: Player) {
        self.owner = owner
    }

    public func contains(deck: Deck) -> Bool {

        let filter = self.cards.contains(where: {
            guard let hasParent = $0.parent else {
                return false
            }
            return (hasParent == deck)
        })

        return filter
    }

    func add(card: Card) {
        guard let thisOwner = self.owner else {
            return
        }
        card.setOwner(player: thisOwner)

        cards.append(card)
    }

}

struct HandManager {
    func addCard(from deck:Deck, player: Player) {

        if (player.hand.contains(deck: deck)) {
            // do nothing
            print ("player already owns a card from this deck")
        }
        else {
            // get first unowned card
            guard let card = self.getFirstUnownedCard(in: deck) else {
                print ("No cards left, all spaces taken")
                return
            }

            player.hand.add(card: card)
        }
    }


    public func getFirstUnownedCard(in deck: Deck) -> Card?
    {
        guard let filter = (deck.cards.filter { (card: Card) -> Bool in
            return (card.owner == nil)
            }.first) else {
                return nil
        }
        return filter
    }
}


// Main

let board = Board.init()

let players = [
    Player.init(name: "Bob")
    , Player.init(name: "Alex")
    , Player.init(name: "Sam")
]

// add card to hand
if let firstDeck = board.decks.first {

    // Force add players cards from first deck
    for p in players {
        let handMgr = HandManager.init()
        handMgr.addCard(from: firstDeck, player: p)
        print (p.name, p.hand.cards)
    }
}



// I want to get a list of all decks with orders
// I want to get a list of all decks with orders and has owners

// I want to get a list of all decks with orders, and owners
// BUT only owners that can satisfy demand, that is: 
//    where player.card.production.units > 0

class CustomFilter {

    public static func decksWithOrders(decks: [Deck]) -> [Deck] {
        return decks.filter({
            return ($0.orders.count > 0)
        })

    }
    public static func filterDecksWithOrdersAndOwners(decks: [Deck]) -> [Deck] {
        let filtered = decks.filter({
            guard let owners = $0.owners else {
                return false
            }
            return (($0.orders.count > 0) && (owners.count > 0))
        })
        return filtered
    }

    public static func whereProductionExistsIn(decks: [Deck])
    {

        let filter1 = CustomFilter.filterDecksWithOrdersAndOwners(decks: decks)

        let filter2 = filter1.filter { (d: Deck) -> Bool in
            guard let owners = d.owners else {
                return false
            }


            let results = owners.filter({ (p: Player) -> Bool in

                return p.hand.cards.filter({ (c: Card) -> Bool in
                    guard let hasProduction = c.production else {
                        return false
                    }
                    return ((c.parent == d) && (hasProduction.units > 0))
                })
            })

            return results

        }

    }
}
```

---

Edit:  I got the filter to remove the bug/error, but I'm still unsure if this is the correct way to do such a complex filter.

```
 let filter2 = filter1.filter { (d: Deck) -> Bool in
            guard let owners = d.owners else {
                return false
            }

            let results = owners.filter({ (p: Player) -> Bool in
                return p.hand.cards.filter({ (c: Card) -> Bool in
                    return (c.parent! == d) && ((c.production?.units)! > 0)
                }).count != 0
            })

            return (results.count != 0)

        }
```

Comment: Didn't check all, but for your compile errors. filter() needs to return a Bool, and you return an array `owners.filter()`, and in `filter1.filter()` too. So `return results` => `return results.count != 0` and `return p.hand.cards.filter({ (c: Card) -> Bool in ...).count != 0`? Or something like that (didn't check your logic/condition, you just have to return a Bool there. Else, +1 for giving a whole Playground project to test.

Comment: I appreciate the asssitance and help on this, I'm sure I'm overcomplicating it anyhow

Comment: I'm finding the formatting a bit hard to read on your reply, is it possible to get an inline one?   thanks

Comment: I was able to clean up the bug by adding `(results.count != 0)` as  indicated.

Comment: @zardon It's preferable to use `!results.isEmpty` over `results.count != 0`. It's more expressive of intent. Also, avoid prefixed SQL commas in array literals. Swift allows a trailing comma at the end of an array or dictionary literal, exactly to avoid the need for such a messy style. I'll try to take a stab at your problem later tonight when I have some more time

Comment: Hi there, I put the commas before array literals because sometimes I forget to put the comma in or other times I put a comma on the last entry when its not needed;   I will try in future to put the commas at the end of each line